# integrating tiny url with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, tinyurl

I have PHP code for shortening a URL. I want to integrate it with CodeIgniter. How can I do this?
I have 3 pages: `index.php`, `page.php` and a `.htaccess` file and one database backup file.

`index.php`

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");

$url=$_GET['url'];
$url_details=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from tinyurls where shorturl like ('".$url."')"));
if(!empty($url_details)){
    header("location: ".$url_details['actualurl']);
}else{
    echo '<h2 style="color:red">Error 404: Page not found</h2>';
}
?>
```

`page.php`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['url'])){
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test");

    $exist=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from tinyurls where actualurl='".$_POST['url']."'"));
    if(empty($exist))
    {
        function get_random_word($length=6){
            $chars='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
            $word="";
            for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
                $word.=substr($chars,rand(1,strlen($chars)),1);
            }

            $isexist=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select id from tinyurls where shorturl like ('".$word."')"));
            if(empty($isexist)){
                return $word;
            }else{
                return "";
            }
        }

        $tiny_word="";
        while($tiny_word==""){  
            $tiny_word=get_random_word();
        }
        mysql_query("insert into tinyurls set shorturl='".$tiny_word."', actualurl='".$_POST['url']."'");
    }else{
        $tiny_word=$exist['shorturl'];
    }
    echo "TinyURL: http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/tinyurl/".$tiny_word."<br/><br/>";
}
?>
<html>
    <head><title>Shorten URL</title></head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
            Enter the URL:<br/>
            <input type="text" name="url" style="padding:5px;width:500px"/><br/><br/>
            <input type="submit" style="padding:5px" value="Shorten URL">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

`.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^p\/(.*)$ page.php?q=$1 [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I integrate it with CodeIgniter?

Comment: when iam integrating this with codeigniter the controller goes to the home page of my site not to the original url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when iam integrating this with codeigniter the controller goes to the home page of my site not to the original url

In your code you're just `echo`ing the URL instead of redirecting it:

```
header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/tinyurl/' . $tiny_word);
```